# How to use psfrag with eps figures created using Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, eps, psfrag

I want to use **`psfrag`** to modify the contents of my **`.eps`** figures.

However, the tags generated by `matplotlib` is saved letter by letter, and doesn't seem to be recognized by `psfrag`.

Did a lot of googling, but couldn't find anything. Please help!

Cheers, 
Emmanuel

Comment: Have you, Emmanuel, tried a single-character tags in matplotlib ( so as to avoid a fragmented string handling ) or have you tried to rethink the architecture, going into PostScript-syntax based post-processing? Both seem viable.

Comment: I tried using single character tags, but that also doesn't seem to work. Has anyone managed to place a .eps figure from Matplotlib in Latex (Im using XeLatex -> pdf)

Comment: I have a vauge memory of this going by on the mailing list / issue tracker.  This is the sort of thing that _should_ work.  Please try the release candidate (1.5.0rc1) and if that does not work email the mailing list.  It would also greatly help if you provided a minimal working code example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

### A sure way to get the job done

In case all psfrag options fail, there is still a way to succeed. EPS is not as magic page-description format as one might feel on a first look.

So, the PS syntax helps us in case an encapsulation-aided EPS file is the way to go:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 70 70 146 146
%%Title: C:\box1.ps
%%Creator: GSview from C:\box1.ps
%%CreationDate: Sat Sep 25 19:58:06 2015
%%Pages: 1
%%EndComments
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginDocument: C:\box1.ps
%!
%% Draws a one square inch box and inch in from the bottom left

/inch {72 mul} def                   % Convert inches->points (1/72 inch)
newpath                              % Start a new path
1 inch 1 inch moveto                 %       an inch in from the lower left
2 inch 1 inch lineto                 %       bottom side
2 inch 2 inch lineto                 %       right side
1 inch 2 inch lineto                 %       top side
closepath                            % Automatically add left side to close path
stroke                               % Draw the box on the paper
showpage                             % We're done... eject the page

%%EndDocument
%%Trailer
```

Lovely Reversed Polish Notation ( RPN ) in the PostScript, isn't it? ( Powerful hidden worlds of PostScript).

Simplicity of real PS/EPS is typically a bit blurred by sometimes machine-generated dictionaries of typographic stuff ( font-families, be them used or not, font-metrics' details for typesetting features ), which is important, but boring to read once we re-process the PS/EPS code for post-mod(s).

Nevertheless, keep to search syntactical-section separators **`%%BeginDocument`** / **`%%EndDocument`** and find **`showpage`** in between these.

**Reading bottom-up** from each **`stroke`** ( commands each PostScript geometrical/typographical-construct to actually be "layout-for-being-printed" by the PS-interpreter processor ( Btw. the first massive-market deployment of RISCs ) ) will bring you near the actual placement of your **`matplotlib`** objects and finding your text/tag you wish to change and change it.

---

**Hard?** No, not really. **Boring?** Might be, however could be algorithmised to suit your needs.

Enjoy the progress ahead, it is definitely doable and faster than waiting for a new mighty update from the package maintainers.